# Default Argument in recursive function retains value after function returns, even though it is explicitly erased

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, keyword-argument

So I have been recently getting back into some python, just to write little scripts. In this script I am getting a bunch of Jira tickets and then I wrote myself a recursive function to flatten them into a flat dictionary structure, for easier filtering. All of that works fine, but one thing stumps me. In the recursive function called `get_flattened_dict` I have made myself to... well, flatten the dictionaries, I created a variable called `mega_dict` that gets spit out in the end, containing the contents of all nested dictionaries from the initial value. This argument has a default value, which is an empty dictionary. On the first run through this works fine. By the end of the function, before returning, I explicitly erase the value of the variable. However, on the second run through of the function, the variable retains the value it was assigned from the initial run through.

Code:

```
# from third_party.python3.atlassian import Confluence
# from third_party.python3.jira import JIRA
from atlassian import Confluence
from jira import JIRA


class ConfluenceHelper:
    def __init__(self, username, api_key):
        # sets up connection to jira api


    def get_jira_tickets(self, jql_query):
        # Gets tickets from Jira with jql query
        return tickets

    def get_flattened_dict(self, field_name, og_dict, calling_from="", lookingfor="", mega_dict={}, original_key=""):
        print("calling from:", calling_from)
        print(bool(mega_dict))
        for dict_key in og_dict.keys():
            if isinstance(og_dict[dict_key], dict):
                calling_from = "recursive"
                mega_dict = self.get_flattened_dict(field_name, og_dict[dict_key], calling_from, lookingfor, mega_dict, original_key=dict_key)
            elif original_key:
                new_key = field_name + "_" + original_key + "_" + dict_key
                mega_dict[new_key] = og_dict[dict_key]
            else:
                new_key = field_name  + "_" + dict_key
                mega_dict[new_key] = og_dict[dict_key]

        return_dict = dict(mega_dict)
        mega_dict = {}
        return return_dict
    
    def get_filtered_tickets(self, tickets):
        field_name = "CustomField"
        filtered_tickets = {}
        for ticket in tickets:
                flattened_dict = {}
                field_value = ticket.raw['fields'][field_name]
                if field_value and isinstance(field_value, list):
                    for list_value in field_value:
                        if isinstance(list_value, dict):
                            callingfrom = "outside"
                            flattened_dict = self.get_flattened_dict(field_name, list_value, callingfrom, str(ticket))
        # Some filtering happening here
        return filtered_tickets

    def nice_text_for_filter(self, filtered_tickets):
        # Create nicer output for human eyes
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Parser Arguments set here
    args = parser.parse_args()
    confluence_helper = ConfluenceHelper(args.username, args.api_key)
    print("Running Script...")
    tickets = confluence_helper.get_jira_tickets(args.jql_query)
    filtered_tickets = confluence_helper.get_filtered_tickets(tickets)
    confluence_helper.nice_text_for_filter(filtered_tickets)
```

Here is some of the output of the print statements set in `get_flattened_dict()`:

```
calling from: outside
False
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: recursive
True
calling from: outside
True
calling from: recursive
```

As you can see, the second time the function gets called from the outside, the dictionary already has a value, even though I explicitly clean it. I just don't understand where that value is coming from.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I much appreciate any answer!